# How to get all friends' page likes using FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I've been using the following FQL, trying to figure out how to get all of my friends' page likes:

```
SELECT name FROM page WHERE page_id IN 
    (SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid IN 
        (SELECT uid1, uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
    )
```

It works somewhat to my liking, but I'm unable to tell which 'uid' belongs to which page name.
Something like the following is returned:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Snoop Dogg"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Good Grief"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Aaliyah"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've also tried using the Graph API, but it times out. Is there some way that I can get my results to look something more like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "uid" : "987234",
      "name": "Snoop Dogg"
    }, 
    {
      "uid" : "987234",
      "name": "Good Grief"
    }, 
    {
      "uid" : "234789",
      "name": "Aaliyah"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If multi-querying is somehow an option in my case, I'm certainly open to that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/[Friend-ID]/likes works fine for me. With the permission "friends_likes", of course. And this also works for me, it just takes some time because it gets the likes of EVERY friend:

```
SELECT page_id, name FROM page WHERE page_id IN 
   (SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid IN 
   (SELECT uid1, uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
)
```

For connecting the Pages to a User, you would need a JOIN. In any case, i would prefer using the Graph API and getting it for only one user.

If you only need the ID of the Page and the User ID, there is a much simpler way if you just use the first Sub-Select:

```
SELECT uid, page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid IN 
       (SELECT uid1, uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

Unfortunately, there is no JOIN in FQL, but there are Multiqueries:

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql

So, query1 would be the last one above, query2 would be something like that:

```
SELECT page_id, name FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM #query1)"
```

Comment: You're first method of using the Graph API won't work in my case where there are a lot of friends. It times out and just simply isn't a reliable solution. This is where FQL is the better option, but you're FQL select statement is selecting the page_id and [page]name fields. I need the name of the page and the uid of the friend that likes that page.

Comment: I preferred to have the page name and uid, as it's the name I'm after. If I have to do multiple queries, I at least hope to use the most optimized and quick method of doing so.

Comment: The multi-query luschn suggested is the fastest way (I think). You get the combination uid and page_id from the first query, and page_id and name from the second – so you have all you need to combine those two data sets to the one you want. I don’t see a way of doing so directly in SQL – but in your processing of the result sets afterwards, you have all you need to combine the data from the two.

Comment: Ended up going with the multiquery. Ran some tests just to be sure that running it, and not 2 separate queries, is faster and it indeed is. Using Javascript is also way faster than server-side (PHP) by my tests.